# How to update and add latest data from one table to another using trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a question hopefully it's very interesting as follows.
I receive data from the API and it is saved to the `records` table daily:

| id | device_id | last_send |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X-001 | 2021-03-18 17:40:00 |
| 2 | X-001 | 2021-03-19 18:50:00 |
| 3 | X-002 | 2021-03-19 17:45:00 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And the `devices` table:

| id | name | last_send_record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X-001 | Device 1 | 2021-03-19 18:50:00 |
| X-002 | Device 2 | 2021-03-19 17:45:00 |

The `id` field in the `devices` table is related to the `device_id` field of the `records` table. The `records` table data is very large, so the join reduces the performance.

Now I want to update data when there is the latest data of field `last_send` in the records table to `last_send_record` in the `devices` table.

If the device does not exist then add the latest record from the `records` table. Please help me, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: We need `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `UPDATE` or `INSERT` that might be helped by a Trigger.

Comment: @RickJames yes. I think that's a good solution, but I don't know how to start yet. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Please help me!!!

Comment: Read about "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE"; it may help with the second task.